# how to do something like a "case when" condition in linq?

Tags: c#, sql, linq

basically i have some data table similar to this

```
| ItemId | RuleId | IsActive |
------------------------------
| ItemA  | RuleA  | FALSE    |
------------------------------
| NULL   | RuleA  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
| ItemC  | RuleA  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
| ItemA  | RuleB  | FALSE    |
------------------------------
| NULL   | RuleB  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
```

and i want to get result like this

for item a

```
| ItemId | RuleId | IsActive |
------------------------------
| ItemA  | RuleA  | FALSE    |
------------------------------
| ItemA  | RuleB  | FALSE    |
------------------------------
```

for item b

```
| ItemId | RuleId | IsActive |
------------------------------
| NULL   | RuleA  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
| NULL   | RuleB  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
```

for item c

```
| ItemId | RuleId | IsActive |
------------------------------
| ItemC  | RuleA  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
| NULL   | RuleB  | TRUE     |
------------------------------
```

basically if there's specific rule, then use the specified, otherwise use the default rule setting with null as itemId

how to achieve this in linq?

Thanks in advance

EDIT: thanks for styling, @lazyberezovsky. @dasblinkenlight I don't have the query for sql either. I do need in linq way, but it's also of great help if anyone can give me some advice how to get the result in sql way.

Comment: sorry but is quiet of hard help you if you don't show us what you have don't so far

Comment: Why you have `NULL` for `ItemC` results?

Comment: Could you show the desired `case/when` in SQL?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: for 'RuleB' there is no ItemC, so it uses the default NULL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't the prettiest LINQ query, but here's a complete code sample that works

```
//the sample data as provided by the OP
var rules = new []
{
    new { ItemId = "ItemA", RuleId = "RuleA", IsActive = false },
    new { ItemId = (string)null, RuleId = "RuleA", IsActive = true },
    new { ItemId = "ItemC", RuleId = "RuleA", IsActive = true },
    new { ItemId = "ItemA", RuleId = "RuleB", IsActive = false },
    new { ItemId = (string)null, RuleId = "RuleB", IsActive = true },
};

//the items that we want to get the rules for
var items = new [] { "ItemA", "ItemB", "ItemC", };

//get the rules for all of the items
var query = from i in items
            let itemRules = from r in rules
                            //we need to prefer rules that match our id
                            orderby r.ItemId ?? "" descending
                            //match on id or null
                            where (r.ItemId ?? i) == i                            
                            group r by r.RuleId into grouping                        
                            //take the best match
                            select grouping.First()
            select new
            {
                i,
                itemRules,
            };
```

and here's the output

[image]

I don't think this will work with LINQ to SQL but it certainly works with LINQ to Objects.  I'll see if I can get a version working with LINQ to SQL when I've got some time to build a test DB.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any language construct in LINQ (it's not called Language Integrated Query for nothing). For example if you use VB.NET - you can use [`CHOOSE` function](http://codecorner.galanter.net/2009/12/17/linq-truly-language-integrated/) directly inside of LINQ query

Answer (score 0):

You can group all items by `RuleId`, then select first item from each group, which has specified `itemId`. If there is no such item, then create and return default item:

```
from i in items
group i by i.RuleId into g
select g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == itemId) ?? 
       new Item { ItemId = null, RuleId = g.Key, IsActive = true }
```

---

This query will work with in-memory items. But you can't create new default item on server side - you will receive an error

> The entity or complex type 'Item' cannot be constructed
>   in a LINQ to Entities query.

So, return anonymous types instead of items, and construct items in memory:

```
(from i in context.Items
 group i by i.RuleId into g
 let item = g.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == itemId)
 select new
 {
     ItemId = item == null ? null : itemId, // default if not found
     RuleId = g.Key,
     IsActive = item == null ? true : item.IsActive
 })
.AsEnumerable() // move to memory
.Select(i => new Item { 
     ItemId = i.ItemId, 
     RuleId = i.RuleId, 
     IsActive = i.IsActive 
});
```

That works with EF.